# Sum Debit and Credit Using for tables-tblraw_suptrans, tblraw_cat and tblraw_supplier

Tags: php, join, mysqli, sum, localhost

I have four table tblraw_supplier(raw_supid, raw_supname), tblraw_cat(raw_catid, raw_catname), tblraw_suptrans(sup_id, invoice, raw_id) and tblpayment(sid, pay_credit, pay_debit).

Below is my code using JOIN

```
$tsql = "select *,sum(pay_debit) debit,sum(pay_credit) credit, sum(pay_credit-pay_debit) total  from tblpayment p JOIN tblraw_suptrans s ON p.sid=s.sid LEFT JOIN tblraw_cat c ON s.raw_id=c.raw_catid LEFT JOIN tblraw_supplier su ON s.sup_id=su.raw_supid Group by p.sid";
$tre = mysqli_query($con,$tsql);
$nrows=mysqli_num_rows($tre);

for ($i=0; $i<$nrows; $i++)
{
    $n=$i+1;
    $trow=mysqli_fetch_array($tre);
    extract($trow);

    echo "<tr>\n
        <td>$n.</td>
        <td>$sup_transdate</td>
        <td>$raw_supname</td>
        <td>$raw_catname</td>
        <td>$raw_count</td>
        <td>$invoice</td>

        <td>$sup_debit</td>
        <td>$credit</td>
        <td>$total</td>

        <td><a href='agsupcredit.php?pid=$sid' class='btn btn-primary'>Enter Pay</a></td>

        </tr>\n";                                       
}
```

Above code work perfectly on localhost but not displaying anything online. I  don't what happen.
Also note that it worked online before.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please clarify what happens "online"? What do you see? Also, could you give a little bit more information regarding what you might have changed since it last worked?

Comment: @GabrielBourgault I can't remember changing anything. It has been working since last year. Not displaying anything online when I use the same data on localhost, it works. Thanks